# Integration of a pdf in the context of an importance sampling with the extended Phong-BRDF

Tags: calculus, integration

I have a problem solving an integral. I try to integrate a pdf $p(\psi,\phi)$ to get a cdf $F(\psi,\phi)$. Then I want to use the inverse method to get stochastic variables $u_1, u_2$ with $u_1 = F^{-1}(\psi, \phi)$ and so on. But I have no idea how to solve the integral. I tried it with a CAS, but with that solution I was not able to transform it right to get the result for the stochastic variables. Maybe someone can explain me this (in small steps)?

This is the integral:
$$
\int_0^\phi \int_0^\psi \frac{n+1}{2\pi}cos(\psi')^nsin(\psi')\partial\psi'\partial\phi'
$$

Thats the solution I found in literature after using the inversion method to get stochastic variables:
$$
\psi = \arccos(1-u_1)^{\frac{1}{n+1}}\\
\phi = 2\pi u_2
$$

I need that to understand an importance sampling with the extended Phong-BRDF and Monte-Carlo-Integration (computergraphics lecture, some literature: http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch20.html).

I would appreciate any help.

Meiner